# Correct usage of the preposition "with"

Tags: phrase-request, phrases

I want to say:

> With help my friend I pass exam.

> Rename folder with help Resharper. [Resharper is a tool for developing.]

> With a sense of self-preservation I jumped over the wall.

Are those sentences correct, or should I use a different phrase, instead of "with help"?

Comment: Tanner has given good feedback on Nos. 1 and 2. No. 3 sounds okay to me, although I'd insert a comma: _"With a sense of self-preservation, I jumped over the wall."_ It might also be reworded as, _"In an act of self-preservation, I jumped over the wall."_ However, since you've provided no context other than that one standalone sentence, it's impossible to tell which of those two would be "better."

Comment: Hi Mediator, welcome to ELL! Can you please identify specific areas in these sentences that you think might not be correct? As it stands your question is simply proofreading, which we do not allow, but if you edit to add why you think they might not be correct/specific areas of concern, the question would be improved.

Answer (score 2):

*With the help of* is probably what you want for the first two sentences:

> With the help of my friend, I passed the exam.
>
> Rename a folder with the help of Resharper.

In the first sentence, "with the help of my friend" could be replaced with "with help from my friend" or "with my friend's help". I don't think "With help from Resharper" and "with Resharper's help" are good options, however.

I'm not sure what you're asking with regards to the third sentence.